# Check user's each request after user logged into the with conditions in Laravel 6.18

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

Ok let me explain my requirement shortly. I have a portal where suppliers can register and add their content to our site. Usually, registration has 5 steps where after the supplier completes the first registration step then the user will be logged into the system and also it also update the `registration_step` column in the DB table. After the supplier completes his 1st step he can log out and then once he logged in again then the user will not be able to go another URL till he completes all steps in registration. SO I have tried to accomplish this with middleware like below. Please note there are 3 different types of users in this system.

```
 class CheckUserRegistrationStep
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $supplier = Auth::guard('supplier');
        if ($supplier->check()) {
            $supplierRegistrationStep = Supplier::findOrFail($supplier->user()->id)->registration_step;
            if ($supplierRegistrationStep == 2) {
                return redirect()->route('suppliers.registration-step02-otp-verification');
            } else if ($supplierRegistrationStep == 3) {
                return redirect()->route('suppliers.registration-step03-nature-of-business');
            } else if ($supplierRegistrationStep == 4) {
                return redirect()->route('suppliers.registration-step04-categories-and-locations');
            } else if ($supplierRegistrationStep == 5) {
                return $next($request);
            }
        } else {
            return back();
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that when I use this middleware in the controller then it gives me the error **too many redirects**. I know this error occurs because the user gets redirected to the same URL again and again. So I have tried with so many methods to accomplish my requirement but still no luck.

Simply I'm trying to stop the user get navigated to other URLs till he completes the registration and I want to redirect the user for the place he stops the registration step.

**Update**

An error that occurs after modifying the code @CleanCode 's answer

> ErrorException
>
> Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object

This is the controller

```
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:supplier', ['except' => ['step01', 'step01Store']]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your'e getting redirected because it's checking the condition and redirecting to the same route but you don't check if the current route is not the redirecting route.
You can add another check to the condition to check if the route isn't the redirecting route.

```php
class CheckUserRegistrationStep
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $supplier = Auth::guard('supplier');
        if ($supplier->check()) {
            $supplierRegistrationStep = Supplier::findOrFail($supplier->user()->id)->registration_step;
            if ($supplierRegistrationStep == 2 && !$request->route()->named('suppliers.registration-step02-otp-verification')) {
                return redirect()->route('suppliers.registration-step02-otp-verification');
            } else if ($supplierRegistrationStep == 3 && !$request->route()->named('suppliers.registration-step03-nature-of-business')) {
                return redirect()->route('suppliers.registration-step03-nature-of-business');
            } else if ($supplierRegistrationStep == 4 && !$request->route()->named('suppliers.registration-step04-categories-and-locations')) {
                return redirect()->route('suppliers.registration-step04-categories-and-locations');
            } else if ($supplierRegistrationStep == 5) {
                return $next($request);
            }
        } else {
            return back();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @CLeanCode thanks for the answer but this doesn't solve the issue. I think you are asking me to add this to the controller. But just imagine if there are already a lot of controllers then I have to update each. So it's not practical. What I'm trying to do is something with middleware. Thanks

Comment: @NipunTharuksha I just added some code to your middleware, I will edit the answer to include your entire code.

Comment: @CleanCode thanks for the reply but it still generate a error. Please see the updated question.Thanks

Comment: @NipunTharuksha are you sure that this error occurs in this middleware? can you check the file/line/stacktrace of the error?

Comment: @CleanCode sorry what do you mean ?. I didn't get you

Comment: @NipunTharuksha whats the file+line that this error occurs in?

Comment: @CleanCode thanks it working. Thank you very much for the help.